# Trouble accessing array of object pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a bit of code to model a bus. The code has an error and I have simplified the problem in the following snippet:

```
struct luggageTag{
    int seat;
    bool luggage;
};

int main(){

    luggageTag *tagBox[36];
    tagBox[2]->luggage = true; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line  
}
```

Why is it that the line

```
tagBox[2]->luggage = true;
```

results in bad access?

Comment: `tagBox[2]->luggage` means `(*tagBox[2]).luggage`, right? So it dereferences `tagBox[2]`. What does `tagBox[2]` point to?

Comment: Ahh, I understand it now. Your comment makes it much clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is a variable much like any other, except that for a pointer, `T* ptr`, its value is expected to be the address of an instance of T in memory.

You've created an array of uninitialized variables - you haven't pointed them at anything.

Think of a pointer as a post-it-note with the location of a thing on it. What you've done is torn 36 blank post-it notes off the top of the stack.

You'll need to create some luggageTag's to point to, but then you'll also be responsible for freeing those objects.

```
struct luggageTag{
    int seat;
    bool luggage;
};

int main(){
    luggageTag *tagBox[36];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
        tagBox[i] = new luggageTag;
    }
    tagBox[2]->luggage = true;
    // memory leak unless you do:
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < 36 ; ++i)
    //   delete tagBox[i];
}
```

Alternatively you could create a pointer to an array of 36 luggage tags:

```
struct luggageTag{
    int seat;
    bool luggage;
};

int main(){
    luggageTag *tagBox = new luggageTag[36];
    tagBox[2]->luggage = true;
    // ...
    delete [] tagBox;  // free the memory
}
```

If this is not part of a school exercise, you might want to look at using a `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `tagBox[2]` is a pointer but it doesn't point anywhere, and you're trying to dereference it.

You will need to make it point to somewhere first, e.g.:

```
luggageTag tag;
tagBox[2] = &tag;
```

But unless there's a specific reason why you would need pointers, you could simply store the actual objects directly in the array:

```
luggageTag tagBox[36];
       // ^ remove *
tagBox[2].luggage = true; // no EXC_BAD_ACCESS!
      // ^ dot, not arrow operator
```

Now there's no need to make the array element point to something first.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate all the objects in the array:

```
 luggageTag *tagBox[36];
 for(int i=0; i<36; i++)
      tagBox[i] = new luggageTag;

 tagBox[2]->luggage = true; 

 for(int i=0; i<36;i++)
        delete tagBox[i];
```